# Null Pointer Exception at Statement stmt = conn.CreateStatement. Am new to this, I cannot find a solution?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

The idea of this program is to connect to a database, using a graphical interface that gives the user options to to alter or update the database. It starts with the DriverManager connection, and methods are written to be called by JRadioButton options (Yes I am aware it is an unusual use of radio buttons). The GUI calls on the methods, but from these methods, despite creating the connection through driver manager, there seems to be a null pointer exception through conn still. I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me why this is still pointing to a null, rather than the DriverManager.getConnection?
Thanks.

```
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Uni",
                    "resit", "summer1");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
```

GUI works fine alone, but does not seem to connect to the database through the DriverManager Connection.

```
        Query myGUI = new Query();

    }

    private static void insertLecturer() throws SQLException {
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert: LID");
        String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert FirstName");
        String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert LastName");
        String d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Salary");
```

This line (below) is pointing to a null connection? But cannot understand or see why?

```
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Lecturer VALUES " + "(" + a + " " + "'" + b
                + "'" + " " + "'" + c + "'" + " " + d + ")" + ";";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    }
```

Using the ActionEvent from the GUI to call the SQL methods.
        }

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

        if (a.getActionCommand() == first) {
            try {
                insertLecturer();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: paste the stack trace pls

Comment: Waaay too much code to wade through, do you have the stack trace? What line is the error on? What is that line? What variable is null? Initialise that so it is not null.

Comment: You never initialize `conn` as you never call `getConnection` (BTW: having an instance variable with the connection is usually a bad idea, having a static variable is even worse)

Comment: I'm afraid I am new to all of this, I have no idea what a stack trace is? And I point out which error it is on, it is the line <Statement stmt = conn.createStatement>

Comment: Have edited question according to your comments, hope it is friendlier now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where you've commented "Creating the Connection object" doesn't actually create any object, so your connection is null.

Use a `DriverManager` to create the `Connection` object first. Any tutorial will show how it's done.

Comment: I have the DriverManager creating the Connection:public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Uni",
                    "resit", "summer1");

Comment: Yea, but you never call getConnection() before trying to create a statement. Remove the `conn` instance variable, and make it a local to your getConnection() method. Then you'll be forced to write correct code (at least concerning this problem).

Comment: Thank you for your response, the conn instance was removed, it was something I had added in to try to fix my problem. But the problem remains, I am using eclipse, and the whole interface suggests there is nothing wrong with my code, which is my issue. The program executes, but it is only when I try to enter the information that it comes up with the null pointer exception in conn. What am I missing/where am I missing the essential link between then creation of conn in the connection and calling it in the main method through the GUI? Again, thanks

Comment: Where ever you use the database connection, make sure you get it with your `getConnection()` method. Every single time.

Answer (score 2):

If you get null pointer exception in the below line,

```
Statement stmt = conn.CreateStatement
```

It means your conn connection object is null. Check your DB configurations.

Add a null check, like this

```
if(conn != null) {
   Statement stmt = conn.CreateStatement

}
```

Comment: That null check is useless. It's an error in the business logic to have the connection be null at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `openDatabase` before calling `getData`?

If you aren't then `conn` is null and `conn.createStatement` will trigger the `null pointer exception`.

try this:

```
if (conn == NULL) 
{ 
openDatabase(); 
}
```

Just ahead of your `conn.createStatement`

```
Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
```

So clearly `conn` is the `null pointer`.

Which means that his line

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
```

presumably did **NOT** manage to give a value to `conn`.

Which probably means that the `DriverManager` can't find the connection he wanted.

Comment: I used neither openDatabase or getData, just DriverManager. In all the tutorials I have looked through all you need it says is to open a connection using the DriverManager, which I do, but somehow the connection is not being retrieved, or is being recreated with a null value? Thank you

Comment: Is it possibly something to do with the connection not being passed through to my GUI? And if that is the case, do you know how I might be able to correct that?